# I am an American citizen with a work permit as a meteorologist in Canada. Can I fly into Canada under the current border closure?

Tags: usa, canada, covid-19

I am an American citizen with a work permit in Canada. (I work as a meteorologist for a hedge fund.) Can I enter Canada by air or land?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. A holder of a valid work permit who has a confirmed employment *or* has their ordinary residence in Canada is exempt from the general entry ban, as their entry is considered non-discretionary. **However, in general, other public health restrictions (testing, quarantine and reporting obligations) will still apply after your entry unless you qualify for an exemption (e.g. essential workers in health care, transportation etc., commuters in cross-border communities).** These measures include a mandatory 3-day hotel quarantine if you are flying.

You can find more information at the Government of Canada's dedicated website https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid.

> The following are examples of non-optional or non-discretionary travel for temporary workers who hold a valid work permit or received a letter of introduction from IRCC on their work permit application and are seeking entry at a Canadian POE:
>
> - A foreign national has a valid work permit and ordinarily resides in
>   Canada. Whether the foreign national’s employment still exists or they
>   are currently laid off is not determinative in this case. What is
>   determinative is that the foreign national’s primary residence is in
>   Canada (suggesting their travel is not optional).
> - A foreign national
>   has a letter of introduction for an open work permit, holds a valid
>   job offer and will be able to work once they enter Canada.
> - A foreign
>   national has a letter of introduction for an employer-specific work
>   permit, holds a valid job offer and will be able to work once they
>   enter Canada.
>
> https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/service-delivery/coronavirus/travel-restrictions/non-optional-non-discretionary.html

Comment: Definitely try to enter by land to avoid paying for overpriced quarantine hotels.